# Kloosterman's identity for deriving the functional equation of the zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

The first paragraph of Section 2.9. of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function* is a follows :

[image]

Even though the Kloosterman's paper is written in German (and I don't speak German), however I tried to find the paper to get a hint if I can prove the identity but it is very much old and not accessible to me. However, I could prove the real case by other means that I couldn't extend to complex case. In addition, the other claim after the identity is not clear as well. My questions are:

1- How Eq. 2.9.1 is derived?

2- How the integrand is $O(|z|^{-\sigma -1})$ is derived? In section 12.16 of Whittaker-Watson's book *A Course of Modern Analysis*, expansion of $\dfrac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}$ is derived but lacks a $\log(z)$ term or I couldn't find a cancelable expansion of $\log(z)$ anywhere.

Comment: Stirling formula gives you the $\log$ term and the difference is $O_{c}(1/z)$ hence the claim about the size of the integrand at infinity; going to the left we pick up residues at each negative integer and those give the Dirichlet series for $\zeta$ when $\Re s>1$; in this latter case the integral goes to zero as near the negative real axis away from integers (eg at half integers) the integrand is $O(|c|^{1-s}))$ so for $\Re s >1$ we get the usual zeta- with more care one can show that if we go to the left enough ($|c| >> |t|$) one gets an oscillating term from the integral with good error)

Comment: Thank you. Tried again and again I got an extra -1 factor : $\lim_{z \to -n} (z+n) e^{i \pi s} z^{-s} \{  -\gamma + \frac{z}{1(z+1)} + \dots + \frac{z}{n(z+n)} + \dots - \log z \} = -n^{-s}$. I took the counterclockwise semicircle where the limit of its diameter is the integrand in the text. Where am I making mistake?

Comment: @Conrad, Sorry I forgot to write your username to notice my previous comment ...

Comment: Looks like you need a minus indeed but that is not that important - the crucial thing is to transform the integral into a real integral as per Titchmarsh chapter $2$

Comment: @Conrad, do you know how to transfer from the complex case to real case? In the book it is written "after the manner of Sec. 2.4." but a part of the counter in that section is on (0,inf) but for this case the situation is not similar and there is log that does not behave like a simple pole..

Comment: something like take $c=-\epsilon$ and then split the integral at $c+i0$ and for the upper part use a contour that goes from $\infty$ to $\sqrt 2 \epsilon$ than an arc from $\sqrt 2 \epsilon$ to $\epsilon+i \epsilon$ and then up on the vertical line and argue that is zero using an arc of circle of large radius and let that radius go to infinity; then let $\epsilon \to 0$ and see what happens on the small circular arc; similarly on the other part from $c+i0$ to $c-i\infty$ now going the other way - one should give you $e^{\pi i s}$ and one $-e^{-\pi i s}$

Comment: @Conrad, yes I took that way first but integral on arc doesn't go to zero. Also another problem is that log(x e^{2 \pi i})=log x +2 \pi i ; it may also effect \Gamma

Comment: why shouldn't the integral on the arc not go to zero (note that the Kloosterman integral can be transformed to a positive axis integral only when $0< \Re s <1$ so you need that); just take $0<s<1$ real positive first and then $|z^{-s}|=|z|^{-s}$ and the other part is $O(1/|z|)$ while $|dz|=R$ so the integral on the part of $|z|=R$ should be then $O(R^{-s})\to 0, R \to \infty$ while similarly for the small circle the integral is $O(r^{1-s}\log r) \to 0, r \to 0$ precisely when $0<s<1$; then the result holds by analytic continuation for all $0< \Re s <1$ where the 2.9.2 integral is well defined

Comment: @Conrad I got it thanks a lot :)

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: @Conrad, Sorry to bother you again. There is an issue that I can't solve: when integrating on the line from $0$ to $\infty$, we write $x e^{2 \pi i}$ and that's how factor $e^{2 \pi i s}$ appears but also $ \log(x e^{2 \pi i})= \log x +2 \pi i$ and integrating exta term $2 \pi i$ is not convergent to zero (it is $\infty$ actually). Should I ask this as a separate question on MSE?

Comment: ask separately - though make sure that the integration variables are correct

Comment: @Conrad, I asked (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4847196/deriving-zetas-dfrac-sin-pi-s-pi-int-0-infty-dfrac-gamma1) but I can't transfer my question!