# Show that $\zeta(s) = - \dfrac{\sin \pi s}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma'(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+x)} - \log x \bigg) x^{-s} dx$.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, residue-calculus, riemann-zeta

The formula $$\zeta(s) = - \dfrac{e^{i \pi s}}{2 \pi i} \int_{c - i \infty}^{c+ i \infty} \bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma'(1+z)}{\Gamma(1+z)} - \log z \bigg) z^{-s} dz \ \ \ (*)$$ can be proved by the calculus of residues for $\sigma > 1$ and the formula holds for $\sigma > 1$ by analytic continuation.

My aim is prove Eq 2.9.2. of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function* which states $$\zeta(s) = - \dfrac{\sin \pi s}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma'(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+x)} - \log x \bigg) x^{-s} dx.$$

We consider two counters $C$ and $D$. $C=C_1 + C_2 + C_3 + C_4$: $C_1$ is the line from $\infty+i0$ to $\rho+i0$; $C_2$ is the arc from $\rho+i0$ to $\rho e^{\frac{3 \pi i}{4}}$; $C_3$ is the line from $\rho e^{\frac{3 \pi i}{4}}$ to $\rho e^{\frac{3 \pi i}{4}} + i \infty$; and $C_4$ is the arc from $\rho e^{\frac{3 \pi i}{4}} + i \infty$ to $\infty+i0$. Integration on $C$ is zero. $D=D_1 + D_2 + D_3 + D_4$: $D_1$ is the line from $\rho+i0$ to $\infty+i0$; $D_2$ is the arc from $\infty+i0$ to $\rho e^{\frac{-3 \pi i}{4}} - i \infty$; $D_3$ is the line from $\rho e^{\frac{-3 \pi i}{4}} - i \infty$ to $\rho e^{\frac{-3 \pi i}{4}}$; and $D_4$ is the arc from $\rho e^{\frac{-3 \pi i}{4}}$ to $\rho+i0$. Integration on $D$ is also zero.

Summing $C$ and $D$ and letting $\rho \to 0$ gives $$\zeta(s) : = - \dfrac{e^{i \pi s}}{2 \pi i} \int_{c - i \infty}^{c+ i \infty} \bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma'(1+z)}{\Gamma(1+z)} - \log z \bigg) z^{-s} dz = - \dfrac{e^{i \pi s}}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{\infty} \bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma'(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+x)} - \log x \bigg) x^{-s} dx - \dfrac{e^{i \pi s}}{2 \pi i} \int_{\infty}^0 \bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma'(1+xe^{2 \pi i})}{\Gamma(1+xe^{2 \pi i})} - \log xe^{2 \pi i} \bigg) (xe^{2 \pi i})^{-s} d(xe^{2 \pi i}) = - \dfrac{e^{i \pi s}}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{\infty} \bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma'(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+x)} - \log x \bigg) x^{-s} dx - \dfrac{e^{i \pi s}}{2 \pi i} \int_{\infty}^0 \bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma'(1+xe^{2 \pi i})}{\Gamma(1+xe^{2 \pi i})} - \log x - \log e^{2 \pi i} \bigg) (xe^{2 \pi i})^{-s} d(xe^{2 \pi i})  = - \dfrac{\sin \pi s}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \bigg( \dfrac{\Gamma'(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+x)} - \log x \bigg) x^{-s} dx - \dfrac{e^{i \pi s}}{2 \pi i} \int_0^{\infty} (- 2 \pi i) (xe^{2 \pi i})^{-s} dx.$$

How that the last term above is zero so that we conclude validity of Eq 2.9.2. ?

Comment: What is your question? In the formula for $\zeta$ stated here you have that $\log x$ is real and that $x^{-s}=e^{-s\log x}$ where $\log x$ is real as well.

Comment: @eulersgroupie Am I right with saying $\log(x e^{2πi})=\log x+2πi$? If so, what happened for the integral including +2πi term then?

Comment: It would only makes sense in a certain context and there it would be abuse of notation. So in general it doesn't make sense and I personally wouldn't write any formula with it in it. If you want to use a certain branch of the logarithm there are more clear ways to express that.

Comment: @eulersgroupie, I re-express my question in another way: When we want to start from that zeta mentioned in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841535/kloostermans-identity-for-deriving-the-functional-equation-of-the-zeta-function to reach the zeta defined in the title of this very OP, we put $xe^{2 \pi i}$ when integration is from 0 to infinity and that's how we got sine, etc. But this substitution of x is problematic in \log

Comment: @eulersgroupie, My aim is to prove the zeta mentioned in OP and is my two paths correct? I combine them to get original one in other post in LHS and the zeta introduced in OP in RHS, but log makes it impossible to.

Comment: The complex logarithm is multivalued, so you can add or subtract any multiple of 2πi. And of course exp(2πi) = 1. So your expression log(x e^(2πi)) is the same as log(x), which takes all values in the set {ln(x) + 2Kπi  |  K ∈ ℤ} (where ln(x) denotes the single-valued, real-valued logarithm on x > 0).

Comment: @eulersgroupie, $x^{-s}$ when integrating from inf to 0 and $(xe^{2 \pi i})^{-s}$ when integrating from 0 to inf. Multiplying each with $e^{s \pi i}$ and summing gives the $sin \pi s$. That $(xe^{2 \pi i})$ in $\log$ causes an extra $2 \pi i$

Comment: @Ali Maybe it would be good to show the full calculation and in which step your problem arises. I might write an answer later.

Comment: @eulersgroupie, one question before writing my calculations in more detail: Taking cut branch of log to be negative real axis, what is the values of $\log z$ in these two cases: when $z$ is from 0 to inf and when $z$ is from inf to 0?

Comment: @Ali What $\log z$ is on your contour depends on your contour and on the value you give it at the "start" (or some fixed point) of the contour.

Comment: @eulersgroupie, I have written in OP what are the two counters

Comment: Dod I understand the integral question correctly? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E100+%28gamma%27%28x%2B1%29%2Fgamma%28x%2B1%29-lnx%29%2Fx%5E%282.5%29

Comment: @BobDobbs In my answer you can see the valid range for $s$ which is $0<\Re s < 1$ which $2.5$ doesn't satisfy.